# C# unknown types

Tags: c#, object

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string input);
```

and object

```
object deserialzeType;
```

how i can parse it class type from object into into this function ?

```
Deserialize<deserialzeType>("text");
```

I am trying deserealize HttpWebResponse into concrete type, but i want to do dynamically. I want call function GetResopnse and in input parameter, class for deserialing into. Something like this:

```
ParseIntoClass result = HttpResponse.GetRespond(ParseIntoClass);
```

Comment: You can't. Your type parameter _must_ be know at compile time for generics. You can't parse it at run time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here... Can you tell us a little bit more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joel said, when using generic types, you cannot dynamically set the type for objects at run time.

In your snippet

```
Deserialize<deserialzeType>("text");
```

"deserializeType" must be a Type recognized by the compiler - it cannot be an Type variable that you've set to be some type recognized by the compiler.